# Proof that $\max_i(d_i^{(n)})/ \sqrt{n}$ tends to $0$ when $\sum_i (d_i^{(n)})^2 / n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-distributions

Let $d_i^{(n)} \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of integer valued sequences such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})^2}{n} = C < \infty
\end{equation}
Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\max_{i\leq n}d_i^{(n)}}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$?

Edit : Is there a way to make true by tweaking the second moment condition. For example, is it true if instead we ask that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})^{2+\epsilon}}{n} = C < \infty$ for some positive $\epsilon$ and/or also that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})}{n} = D > 0$

For context, I am working on a dynamic for a class of $n$ sized empirical distributions. I feel like there should a relatively "obvious" way to prove this but I fail to see the starting point from which the proof should be attacked.

Comment: What are you taking the maximum over? Do you mean $\max_i(d_i^{(n)})$? If so, it is clearly not true. I am having trouble interpreting your statement in any way such that it would be true. Also, could you specify which small o-notation you are using?

Comment: My formulation was atrocious... I gave more precision

Comment: Great, it is much clearer now, so I can say for certain it is not true. The limit property of your sequence of sequences only "controls" the $n$ first entries in $\lbrace d_i^{(n)}\rbrace_i$. Thus, a counter-example would be the sequence of sequences 
\begin{align}
d_i^{(n)} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }i\leq n \\
i & \text{if }i>n
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This would definitely satisfy your limit, but the maximum is infinite, and so clearly is the latter limit.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting more insight. I know I'm asking a lot but what if i add the condition (i just edited it) that the max is over $i \leq n$?

Comment: If $d_i^{(n)} = 0$ when $i\ne n$ and $d_n^{(n)}=\sqrt{n}$ then both limits are $1$.

Comment: Final question and i'll close it. Is there a way to make this true by tweaking the condition? Say for example by requiring that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})^{2+\epsilon}}{n} = C < \infty$ for some positive $\epsilon$ and/or that also $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(d_i^{(n)})}{n} = D > 0$

(Edited the question for precision again)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think any reasonable conditions will save your conjecture. The example @Sam gave (or at least a modification such that we actually have integers) will make every sequence and every series convergent, but the maximum can be made arbitrarily big. 
This is a good example of the fact that convergence of a sequence/series does not mean the sequence/series is very controlled in each entry. Only the "tail" is controlled.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I forgot it was an integer sequence, so let $d_i^{(n)}=[\sqrt{n}]$.

Comment: Thank you folks! I've been trying to expand the conditions but it has not been fruitful yet. I found a similar problem as an exercise in textbook, i will try to follow from there...